# c++, windows 7: recognize usb thumbdrive was connected and recognize usb identifier?

Tags: c++, winapi, usb-drive

I'd like to write a software that automatically copies some files onto a usb thumbdrive when it gets connected to the usb port. for this i would like to know:

1. how can I write a c++ application that gets notified when a usb thumbdrive gets connected?
2. is there any way to identify the usb thumbdrive, so that i can keep track off whether or not a new usb thumbdrive was inserted already?

Comment: Look into writing a short Powershell script to do this. C++ can of course do it, but it is way overkill

Comment: Is this for a virus? Are you on work placement in Iran?

Comment: Is this specific to one particular thumbdrive (i.e. do you need to identify it by its serial) or do you want to do this for every thumbdrive, external harddisk, MP3 player, photocamera... ?

Comment: :) it's not for a virus. it's for an embedded system

Comment: i want to do this for many thumbdrives, but the thumbdrives will be all of the same type. Also, I want to know whether or not a thumbdrive was already inserted - and preferrably this should not be based on the files on the thumbdrive, but ideally through identifying some serial number or so.

Answer (score 2):

i think you can use the WM_DEVICECHANGE window message to be notified when a device is inserted or removed from the system, here is a link for further reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Krister's answer covers the basics. What he doesn't metion is how to do (2), idenifying it. You're looking for the [`DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363244.aspx) arrival event. This event contains a `dbcc_name`, which is identifies the exact device. (Provided that the device adheres to the USB specification and has a unique serial number; don't expect cheap Chinese devices to.)